# Can we use Face ID and NFC cards with Azure AD B2C login to avoid user submitting credentials every time they login?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We have several Azure AD B2C applications for user login. We are thinking of implementing hardware login to avoid user to login in credentials (username and password). They can just get logged in with NFC cards or faceId

Answer (score 0):

An example of an app, which has been integrated [using AppAuth for iOS](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS) with Azure AD B2C and uses Touch ID to protect access to the refresh tokens that are issued by Azure AD B2C, can be found at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/tree/master/AppSamples-iOS-TouchID-master.

You should be able to extend this to Face ID.